# format double value to two decimal places in EL expression in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

How can I format the double value salary to two decimal places in %{emp.salary}

## Code in jsp page below

```
<input type='text' name='salary' value='<s:property value="%{emp.salary}"/>' />
```

I know how to do it in servlet/POJO classes and send it correctly. My question is how to do it on the jsp page inside the el expression.

Also I already know it is not the best way . But I want to know if it can be done.

Comment: Use <fmt:formatNumber value=${emp.salary} maxFractionDigits=2/>.

Comment: @praki  Thanks. will look into <fmt:formatNumber />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use bellow code to number format :

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" value="${emp.salary}" />
```

But if you want to use the `s:property` any way then this could help.

```
<s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00}',{emp.salary})"/>
```

---

For curious mind **udaybhaskar**.

How to find this `getText()` solution:

frankly speaking I didn't tried to learn them  I tried to found a solutoion. 
For example in this case to format the double number.
I knew I need to to use a nested tag.
like:

`<s:property value="somethig/ possiblly another tag for format"/>`

I find out `<s:text>` do some text formating. so I go [there](https://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html) . In search of something like.
`<s:property value="<s:text  name="?" />"/>`

If you go to the bottom you will find out a suggestion (a little one) saying to use getText().
Which actaully a method in `ActionSupport`class of struts. [ActionSupport](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html)

There are many version of getText().

In the `<s:text>` documentation page it  also recommend to see `MessageFormat`. Because getText() use this MessageFormat to format the text. Now go to 
 [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html?is-external=true)  and try to understand **Patterns and Their Interpretation** .

And finally gel them all together.

So once again I dint learn I find out.

Comment: This is awesome. Can you please suggest me any tutorials for learning OGNL. Official documentation is too vague at least for me.http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html

Comment: actually  I like search based learning :p. Here is another documentation, but I find it more  easy to understand than the official OGNL http://www.javatpoint.com/EL-expression-in-jsp . also check "tutorialspoint"  they have a basic tutorial. Glad to help @udaybhaskar

Comment: @Saif Thank u for reply.All tutorials which are existed online are pretty basic.No tutorial is teaching how to format numbers using EL. For example where did you found out this getText() function.Those number formatting patterns where in the hell you learned it.I tried to customize it but can't do it because i don't know how it will work.

Comment: @udaybhaskar i replied but it was big i couldn't add it in the comment so i edited the answer for you with the answer "how i find this :P". waiting for your feedback :) . May be it will help you to understand now.

Comment: sorry @Raj bro to terrorise you with all the notification :( .

Comment: That was great. That was way hell of finding and mixing .But you found the solution.Thanks @Saif .You showed me another perspective of learning.But you showed a gate for me to learn.That is exactly what i'm looking for .

Comment: People like you @Saif making stack Overflow awesome.You know i have been searching online for this kind of help since so many days.The way you showed effort to taught me what you know is very much appreciable.

Comment: This is what we meant to do, helping each other no big deal. Glad it helped. It was nice to comm with you bro @udaybhaskar .